# Contacts numbers get repeated in phonegap application

Tags: cordova

Using this tutorial [cordova_contacts_contacts](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html), I try to get contact list having name and numbers and I get all this thing properly but there is problem having retrieving the numbers. 
when I am going to read contact list, same number repeated  (for some numbers only). Like this

Name abc,

Phone no. 1234,

Phone no. 1234

This problem scenes only on device.

below is my code please figure out my problem.

```
 var s = "";

for (var i=0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    var contactInfo = contacts[i];
    if ((contactInfo.name != null) && (contactInfo.phoneNumbers != null)){
        s += "Name : " + contactInfo.name.formatted + ", Birthday : " +contactInfo.birthday;

        for (var j=0; j < contactInfo.phoneNumbers.length; j++) {
            s += ", Contacts Type : " + contactInfo.phoneNumbers[j].type + " & No : " + contactInfo.phoneNumbers[j].value;
        }

        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=s;

        console.log(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by using following code:

```
var s = "";
for (var i=0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    var contactInfo = contacts[i];

    if (contactInfo.name != null){
        s += i+1+")" + "Name : " + contactInfo.name.formatted + "<br>";

        if (contactInfo.phoneNumbers != null){
            for (var j = 0; j < contactInfo.phoneNumbers.length; j++){
                if ((j != 0) && ((contactInfo.phoneNumbers[j-1].value) == (contactInfo.phoneNumbers[j].value)))
                    console.log("same no");
                else
                    s += "Contacts Type : " + contactInfo.phoneNumbers[j].type + " & No : " + contactInfo.phoneNumbers[j].value + "<br>";
            }
        }

        if (contactInfo.emails != null){
            for (var k = 0; k < contactInfo.emails.length; k++) {
                if ( (k != 0) && ((contactInfo.emails[k-1].value) == (contactInfo.emails[k].value)))
                    console.log("same email");
                else
                    s += "Email Type : " + contactInfo.emails[k].type + " & email : " + contactInfo.emails[k].value + "<br>";
            }
        }

        if (contactInfo.birthday != null){
            s += ", Birthday : " + contactInfo.birthday;
        }

        s += "<br><br>"
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=s;
```